# How can get dynamic text box data from bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery

Below code is for getting filename from database. I am getting response from database. I have added response in html in script and listing works fine.

" responseText.exploded_filename[i]" is the filename.

Please find the image I have attached [image: Click Here]

When I click "Add Details" button. Bootstrap model will show.

Please find the image [image]

My problem is when I add title for second filename and click save, alert will show only first filename title.

eg: For " Localization " file I edit the title as something like "test" and i clicked on save the alert is showing the first page name "reference" title.

```
var i = 0;
if(responseText.success == true){
        $(".filename").after('<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default download" href="" data-file="">'+responseText.exploded_filename[i]+'</a> <a href="" class="removeProcessEntryFile" style="color: #333; cursor: pointer;"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_'+i+'" data-whatever="@mdo">Add Details</a></a><br><div class="modal fade" id="myModal_'+i+'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add File Details</h4> </div> <div class="modal-body"> <form action="" method="POST" name="formFileDetails_'+i+'" id="formFileDetails_'+i+'"> <div class="form-group"> <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Title</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleFileDetails" name="titleFileDetails" value="'+responseText.exploded_filename[i]+'"> </div> <div class="form-group"> <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Description</label> <textarea class="form-control" id="descriptionFileDetails" name="descriptionFileDetails"></textarea> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveFileDetails_'+i+'">Save</button> </div></form> </div></div> </div> </div>');

  $("#saveFileDetails_"+i).on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var processEntryId         = $("#entryID").val();
      var titleFileDetails       = $("#titleFileDetails").val();
      var descriptionFileDetails = $("#descriptionFileDetails").val();
      alert(titleFileDetails);
      /* $.post("/customers/list/process/entries/file/details", {processEntryId: processEntryId, titleFileDetails: titleFileDetails, descriptionFileDetails: descriptionFileDetails}, function(response){
      });*/
    });
i++;
```